# HttpClient request failing sometimes in C#

Tags: c#, httpclient, azure-webjobs

I have the similar code in my C# Windows application.

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendHttpRequest()
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = null;
    try
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        string accessToken = await GetBearerToken(resourceUrl, clientId, clientSecret, tokenProviderUrl);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken))
            httpRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", ("Bearer " + accessToken));

        response = await client.SendAsync(httpRequest);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        log.Error("Exception raised while sending HTTP request");
        log.Error("Exception details : " + ex.Message);
    }           

    return response;
}

public async Task<string> GetBearerToken()
{           
    HttpResponseMessage response = null;
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    string token = "";
    try
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, tokenProviderUrl);
        request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string> {
            { "client_id",clientId},
            { "client_secret", clientSecret },
            { "grant_type", "client_credentials" },
            { "resource", resource },
        });

        response = await client.SendAsync(request);                
        var payload = JObject.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
        token = payload.Value<string>("access_token");                
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException ex)
    {
        log.Error("Error in GetToken : " + ex.Message.ToString());
    }
    return token;
}
```

The above code works perfectly fine for most the times. But once in a while it throws an exception saying "Task was Cancelled". So according to few questions and articles , I figured out that there can be 2 reasons for this.

1. Request Timeout.
2. Or request was actually cancelled.

I have checked this variable: `CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested`. It returned false. So I'm assuming it is Timeout issue. To base this timeout, I have also checked the time difference between the request started and exception thrown. It is exactly 100 seconds (which is default time of httpClient).

Now when I retry the same request immediately after 5-10 seconds, it is returning success.As this issue is not occurring for every request, I'm bit confused as to what is happening.

The same request executed successfully 95% of the times and rest 5% of the times, it says Task was cancelled.

Is there any scenario where the same Task is executed once and cancelled once.

I have send request through Postman for the Web API and not once I received this issue. It is only through Windows app I'm facing this.

Is there anything am I missing?

### Edit

Inner Exception is null.

> Stack Trace : at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at
> System.Net.Http.HttpClient.d__58.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()

Comment: This seems familair to an issue of my own last week. You might want to investigate if the client is disconnected during the time of the request.

Comment: @RazorShorts How do I check that?

Comment: Inspect the complete exception  stack  ( or log it ) during SendHttpRequest() function. Instead of only logging the exception message. There even might be a an innerexception which has more details what went wrong.

Comment: @RazorShorts I have updated my answer to include Stack Trace as well.

Comment: Do you create `new HttpClient()` on each call?

Comment: @mtkachenko yes.

Comment: @CrazyCoder https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't make a new HttpClient everytime you want to post.
make a new HttpClient in your main method and just pass it in your 
"SendHttpRequest".
I had similar issiues with Task canceling so I searched some and used this.
it worked for me

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Keep-Alive", "false");
        client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
```