# Azure VM gets disconnected from network very often

Tags: c#, azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-keyvault, vnet

I have a Windows service running on Azure VM. The service constantly accesses KeyVaults and Web APIs to run some tasks.

The logs in my service show this message sometimes while accessing keyvault. Most of the times service can access keyvault, but sometimes I get this error:

> System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved:
> 'keyvault.vault.azure.net'.

When I connect to VM through RDP, sometimes I get disconnected with the following message and immediately connects after few seconds.

[image]

But when I see System Logs in Control panel, it shows no error message at that time.

I also have another issue while making an HTTP request to Web API as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53150544/8930751) question.

So my question is, can all these be related to one another? Is it possible that VM is getting disconnected very often from the network and due to this, all the above-mentioned things are happening? How can I test and conclude this?

Comment: @John, so is it possible that the task which is getting cancelled is because of network issue?

Comment: highly unlikely this is an issue on Azure side. i've never seen anything like this and I operate hundreds of VM on Azure daily. is your vm overwhelmed with load?

Comment: @4c74356b41 , No, it is not overloaded at all. All it has is one windows service running. If not Azure, can this be issue with network or VNet?

Comment: well, I certainly didnt observe such a behavior. I'd advice you create a new vm in a different vnet and see if it helps.

Comment: @4c74356b41 I've reviewed your profile and see that you're passionate about Azure. I've removed my comments, but I still defend that it is relevant to the conversation that there are occasional observable hiccups in Azure's networking, and this could be what OP is seeing.

Comment: Perhaps the service API is imposing throttling to your VM?

Answer (score 1):

The times i have seen issue like this it is due to OS performance issue.  It could be memory, CPU or even network throttling but almost certain performance issue.

Make sure the VM sku you are on is able to handle application performance.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sizes

Hope this helps.

Comment: This answer is so general it could apply to anything

Comment: So is the question. Connection dropping can be anything, not even a rocket scientist can give a specific answer with information provided. He needs to focus on performance investigation to narrow down an issue to get a solution for issue.

Comment: Which is why we post comments below the question to garner additional info from the OP before answering

Comment: I have seen this multiple time.  The issue is performance, the answer to the questions is to do a performance investigate.